# How to return a 2D String

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array, hashmap

I do not fully understand how to return a 2D object. So I wrote a method that takes in an input with a document and I have to return a list of all unique words in it and their number of occurrences, sorted by the number of occurrences in a descending order. It is a requirement that I cannot control that this be returned as a 2-dimensional array of String.

So here is what I have so far:

```
static String[][] wordCountEngine(String document) {
    // your code goes here
    if (document == null || document.length() == 0)
        return null;

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    String[] allWords = document.toLowerCase().split("[^a-zA-Z]+");

    for (String s : allWords) {
        if (map.containsKey(s)) {

            int newVersion = (Integer.parseInt(map.get(s).substring(1, map.get(s).length())) + 1);
            String sb = Integer.toString(newVersion);
            map.put(s, sb);
        } else {
            map.put(s, "1");
        }
    }

    String[][] array = new String[map.size()][2];
    int count = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        array[count][0] = entry.getKey();
        array[count][1] = entry.getValue();
        count++;
    }

    return array;
}
```

I'm trying to use a HashMap to store the words and their occurrences. What is the best way to store key --> value pairs from a table into a String[][].
If the input is:

```
input:  document = "Practice makes perfect. you'll only
                get Perfect by practice. just practice!"
```

The output should be:

```
output: [ ["practice", "3"], ["perfect", "2"],
      ["by", "1"], ["get", "1"], ["just", "1"],
      ["makes", "1"], ["only", "1"], ["youll", "1"]  ]
```

How do I store data like this in a 2D array?

Comment: That's a terrible idea, as you're using Strings to represent numeric data. Why not simply return a `Map<String, Integer>` or create a custom type that holds String and int values?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah, I think your right. I'm better off creating my own Data type to store the values in. This was a coding challenge, so I had to return a String[][]. Not my choice. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Hmph, well, I don't approve of their requirements.

Comment: *"This was a coding challenge, so I had to return a String[][]. Not my choice."* Coding Challenges are not the best way to learn **Java**. You better go your way through the official tutorial first: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 7):

`String[][]` simply is the wrong data structure for this task.
You should use a `Map<String, Integer> map` instead of `<String, String>` during the method run and simply return exactly that map.

This has multiple reasons:

- you *store* integers as strings, and even do calculations by parsing the String to an integer again, calculating and then parsing back - bad idea.
- The returned array does not guarantee the dimensions, there is no way to enforce that each sub-array has exactly two elements.

---

Note regarding your comment: *if* (for some reason) you *need* to convert the map to a `String[][]` you can certainly do that, but that conversion logic should be separated from the code generating the map itself. That way the code for `wordCountEngine` remains clean and easily maintainable.

Comment: Overuse of Strings to represent non-text data is a design smell. This is the appropriate solution.

Comment: This was a coding challenge and they wanted a String[][] as a return value. But thanks anyways.

Comment: @RockySingh I added a note regarding that situation.

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you need to return a particular typed data-structure does not mean you need to create similarly typed map inside your method. Nothing prevents you from using `Map<String, Integer>` and then converting it to `String[][]`:

Here is the code that does not use Java8 streeams:

```
static String[][] wordCountEngine(String document) {
        // your code goes here
        if (document == null || document.length() == 0)
            return null;

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for ( String s : document.toLowerCase().split("[^a-zA-Z]+") ){
            Integer c = map.get(s);
            map.put(s, c != null ? c + 1: 1);
        }

        String[][] result = new String[ map.size() ][ 2 ];

        int count = 0;
        for ( Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : map.entrySet() ){
            result[count][0] = e.getKey();
            result[count][1] = e.getValue().toString();
            count += 1;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

And for fun a Java8 version:

```
static String[][] wordCountEngine(String document) {
    // your code goes here
    if (document == null || document.length() == 0)
        return null;

    return Arrays
    //convert words into map with word and count
    .stream( document.toLowerCase().split("[^a-zA-Z]+") )
    .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( s -> s, Collectors.summingInt(s -> 1) ) )
    //convert the above map to String[][]
    .entrySet()
    .stream().map( (e) -> new String[]{ e.getKey(), e.getValue().toString() } )
    .toArray( String[][]::new  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my Solution to Pramp's question although in C# I think it is the same Idea

```
   [TestMethod]
        public void PrampWordCountEngineTest()
        {

            string document = "Practice makes perfect. you'll only get Perfect by practice. just practice!";
            string[,] result = WordCountEngine(document);
            string[,] expected =
            {
                {"practice", "3"}, {"perfect", "2"},
                {"makes", "1"}, {"youll", "1"}, {"only", "1"},
                {"get", "1"}, {"by", "1"}, {"just", "1"}
            };
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected,result);

        }
        public string[,] WordCountEngine(string document)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> wordMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            string[] wordList = document.Split(' ');
            int largestCount = 0;
            foreach (string word in wordList)
            {
                string lowerWord = word.ToLower(); // can't assing to the same variable

                //remove special/punctuation characters
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var c in lowerWord)
                {
                    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
                    {
                        sb.Append(c);
                    }
                }
                string cleanWord = sb.ToString();
                if (cleanWord.Length < 1)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                int count = 0;
                if (wordMap.ContainsKey(cleanWord))
                {
                    count = wordMap[cleanWord];
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    count = 1;
                }
                if (count > largestCount)
                {
                    largestCount = count;
                }
                wordMap[cleanWord] = count;
            }

            // we have a list of all of the words in the same length in a given cell of the big list
            List<List<string>> counterList = new List<List<string>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < largestCount + 1; i++)
            {
                counterList.Add(new List<string>());
            }
            foreach (var word in wordMap.Keys)
            {
                int counter = wordMap[word];
                counterList[counter].Add(word);
            }

            string[,] result = new string[wordMap.Keys.Count,2];
            int key = 0;
            //foreach list of words with the same length we insert the count of that word into the 2D array
            for (var index = counterList.Count-1; index > 0; index--)
            {
                var list = counterList[index];
                List<string> wordListCounter = list;
                if (wordListCounter == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                foreach (var word in wordListCounter)
                {
                    result[key, 0] = word;
                    result[key, 1] = index.ToString();
                    key++;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```